# Implement Lottie animations in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

I want to implement this **Lottie animation** using **Flutter code** and change the text inside it **dynamically**, is there any way or package to do that?

the animation:
https://lottiefiles.com/animations/lower-third-animation-UMOzlnEHi2

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To change the name of a Lottie image, you typically need to edit the JSON file associated with the Lottie animation.

```
1.Download JSON File.
2.Open the JSON File: Open the JSON file in a text editor or a specialized JSON editor.
3.Search for the Layer Name: Use the search function in your text editor to find the name you want to change.
4.Edit the Name: Once your located the layer name in the JSON file, simply edit it to the desired new name.
5.Save the Changes.
6.Re-import the Lottie Animation to flutter project.
```

Comment: That is not totally functional, since I want to use it as a widget and change it is values dynamically.